# RegEx including last word with newline character

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to use RegEx to split up a logfile into groups that later go into a database. For some reason I cannot get the last group to include the last word of the string with the new line character.

My log file I am parsing looks something like this:

```
12:00:01 GRP this is a test1
12:02:03 TES here something else has happend
12:32:22 MCH This processe is finished
```

---

I want to group them into three groups

```
Time
3-letter code
Text
```

Currently in Python I am using this:

```
def parse (s):
    mO = re.search ('([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]) (\w*) (\w.+) ',s)
    if mO:
     print "1: "+mO.group(1)
     print "2: "+mO.group(2)
     print "3: "+mO.group(3)
```

The result I get is:

```
1: 12:00:01
2: GRP
3: this is a
1: 12:02:03
2: TES
3: here something else has
1: 12:32:22
2: MCH
3: This processe is
```

Constantly missing the last word in the string that the new line is attached to. I tried adding \n\r in all variations but after 1 day of search totally lost.

any help much appreciated.

Comment: remove the extra whitespace at the end of your regex.

Comment: that did it, thanks! Could have looked forever on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `'(\w.+) '`,  `+` captures(`()`) all(`.`) characters eagerly until it finds the *last* white space.

```
   # Extra tail whitepace removed   
   mO = re.search ('([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]) (\w*) (\w.+)',s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a well-formed log file (all the lines look the same) I would not overcomplicate it with regex and use plain split

```
def parse(s):
  time, code_3_letter, message = s.split(None, 2)
  # ...
```

[Keep it simple!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 0):

i have a lot of experience with regular expressions and log parsing. (its part of my job)

what you want to do is instead of using a regular expression to search the whole file, you want to feed lines of the file into a regular expression. this will give you much better performance, instead of having the whole file in memory, only 1 line at a time. also the regular expression can then use `match` which is much faster than anything else. here is how i would do it:

```
import re

def parse_logs(file_path):
    results = []
    regex = re.compile(r'(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) (\S\S\S) (.+)')
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            ms = regex.match(line.strip())
            if not ms:
                continue
            results.append([ms.group(1), ms.group(2), ms.group(3)])
    return results
```

or, for an even better approach, turn it into a generator:

```
def parse_logs(file_path):
    regex = re.compile(r'(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) (\S\S\S) (.+)')
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            ms = regex.match(line.strip())
            if not ms:
                continue
            yield (ms.group(1), ms.group(2), ms.group(3))
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Two option. I will see how the split performs.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and shorter regex:

```
[0-2][0-9](:[0-9]{2}){2} [A-z]{3} .*$
```

This matches a valid time (based on your input format) followed by a space, three letters*, another space, and then matches everything until the end of the line.  This will allow the 'Text' portion to be captured even it contains punctuation, etc.

* [A-z] will match lowercase letters, if that is not desired use [A-Z] instead